# Is there a difference between the various 3-volume sets of The History of Middle-Earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Throughout the years, a few 3-volume sets of HoMe were released. The latest was released in 2020.

In the past, I have checked pictures and comparisons of these sets with one another and with the paperback editions. It seems that they were almost identical to one another, and more or less identical to the paperback editions. By this I mean that they had the exact same content, down to the pagination and font sizes. Of course, each volume of the 3-volume sets combines a few of the paperback volumes, bound together in one hardcover book; but, other than that, it seemed that there were no differences.

However, I wonder if the same is true for the newest 3-volume set. At least according to its details online, it seems it has more pages. Does it feature more content? Or is this just a mistake, or some blank pages that are counted for technical issues?

I was also recently told in a comment to [a meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13470/how-can-i-pose-this-question-without-it-being-flagged-as-a-duplicate) that 3-volume sets have tiny print. Is this perhaps the case for the newest edition (which I'm pretty sure it wasn't for the previous ones)?

Comment: Page numbers are irrelevant, they depend on page size, typeface size and gutters etc.

Comment: @Paulie_D The page numbers are meaningless themselves; but, if even the pagination is the same, it means that certainly the content is the same. Or so I figured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is no significant difference in textual content

The content of the various three volume History of Middle-earth sets is the same as the original 12 volume hardback and trade paperback sets, including the pagination.

This was done on the request of Christopher Tolkien, who felt that retypsetting the books would introduce more errors than was worth.

> The text in the Deluxe edition of The History of Middle-earth ('Deluxe' referring to the binding - the interior pages are the same as the corresponding hardback editions) was sourced from printed copies of the individual hardback editions published originally by George Allen & Unwin or HarperCollins between 1983 and 1996. No digital print files of books from that era were available and the original printing films/plates had been discarded by the printer.
>
> ...It was agreed with Christopher Tolkien that we should not attempt to reset the books for the omnibus editions, because of the possibility that this could introduce new errors, and is the reason why, for example, the folio numbers restart with each book within the volumes rather than being continuous.
>
> <sub>[August 10th 2020 email from HarperCollins's Tolkien Team, quoted on TolkienGuide.com](https://www.tolkienguide.com/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?post_id=26167#forumpost26167)</sub>

The main differences between the three volume and twelve volume sets are really just the books binding and matter of presentation. People generally do not recommend the three volume set for reading, as the volumes are much heavier and the pages thinner.

I think the only editions of The History of Middle-earth with different paginations are the del rey mass market paperbacks, (which only cover the first five books).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful (as always). I'd prefer the 12 volume set as well, but it is in practice more expensive to buy them (and time consuming to find them), at least where I live.